# Install.aspx file issue while upgrading Evoq Content

Tags: dotnetnuke

Currently my application is running on Evoq Content 7.3 and I was trying to upgrade it to Evoq Basic 8.5. I have copied the upgraded file into my application directory And now when I try to access the http://MYWEBSITE/install/install.aspx?mode=upgrade , It is giving error "resource can not found Requested URL: /install/install.aspx.

Please advise.

Comment: Do you mind removing most of the upper case in your question title? You are "yelling".

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some files were removed from the install directory, probably as part of a security precaution.  I'm not sure why they were not added back with the upgrade package.

You might be able to fix this by copying the install directory from an appropriate install package.  Just the install directory.

As always, make a copy of your database and complete file directory first, just in the event that what you do fails.